# Throw an error in read_csv if the number of rows does not match the number of headers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large number of `csv` files, where I am trying to identify if the records in the files are consistent with a predefined schema. For example, given a csv :

```
col1,co2,col3,col4,col5,col6
A,B,,C,D,E
M,N,O,,,
U,V,W,
```

The first row is consistent as it has as many entries as the header ( even though there is a missing value). The second row is also consistent, as it has as many entries as the header, but the third row is inconsistent, as it has 3 entries only.

I am looking for a way in `pandas.read_csv` to raise and error for row number 3, but as of now, when I read the file in pandas, it reads all the rows with NA for missing values in row 3. I've tried playing with `error_bad_lines` and `na_filter`, but that does not solve my problem.
Any ideas how can I go about this issue? I don't want to iterate over every row in the csv as some of the files are fairly large and it would take a few mins per file, which isn't going to work out for me.

Comment: The second row has 6 cells but the header has 4 columns. Even if we were to disconsider the missing value, how is it consistent?

Comment: right, thanks for pointing out the error. I've fixed the example

Comment: The second row has 5 values not 6, shouldn't there be one more coma?

Comment: each row should have n-1 commas, where n is the number of headers

Comment: if you're fine with a shell solution, this would give you the lines of `data.csv` that don't have 6 csv fields: `awk -F, 'NF!=6 {print NR}' <data.csv`

Comment: I'm currently only looking for a solution, ideally within pandas, since I'm going to process the data further for downstream analaysis. . Thanks for a solution though!

Answer (score 0):

Well `error_bad_lines` will make sure there are no extra columns. As for missing columns, there is unfortunately no way to check for these without iterating over the data. You can do this with `assert(not df.isnull().values.any())`.